# Smallest Topology on X x Y needed such that Canonical Projections be Continous

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

given two topological spaces X and Y there is a proposition in Topology and Calculus which states that the smallest topology on the product topology, X x Y, such that the canonical projections: p(x,y)=x and p(x,y)=y be continous is the product topology. I need to prove this, which i cant.

I guess that one way to handle it should be the following: consider al different topologies on X x y such that the canonical projections are continous. Then one should take the intersection of all these topologies on X x Y which should be equal to the product toplogy. One should then eventually prove that this intersection ( the product topology ) is such that the canonical projections are continous. How can i show this ?

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Let $\tau$ be a topology on the product such that the projections are continuous. Show that $\tau$ is finer than the product topology.

Comment: It is a tautology in a way, because the product topology is **defined** to be the minimal topology that makes all projections continuous. So do you have some other definition which would make it provable in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\scr{T}$ be the set of all topologies on $X \times Y$ such that $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ are continuous, this set is non-empty as the discrete topology is in it.

So $\mathcal{T} = \cap \scr{T}$ is well-defined and one easily checks using the definition of a topology that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology if all members of $\scr{T}$ are topologies (which they are).

Now if $O$ is open in $X$ resp. $Y$, then $(\pi_X)^{-1}[O]$, resp. $(\pi_Y)^{-1}[O]$ is an open set in every topology in $\scr{T}$, as these topologies are defined to make both of $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ continuous. So $(\pi_X)^{-1}[O]$ (Resp. $(\pi_Y)^{-1}[O]$) is in $\mathcal{T}$ by the definition of intersection, making $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ continuous w.r.t. $\mathcal{T}$, which is defined to be the product topology. This can be extended to a general existence proof for so-called initial topologies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It remains however unclear that you are asserting that the intersection is defined to be the product topology. It would be more natural to prove that the intersection of the topologies is the product topology itself. Otherwise everything you are saying is very clear. If you got any idea please give me an asnwer. Thanks.

Comment: @user249018 what is your definition of product topology ? The intersection is mine.

Comment: My definition is that of the cartesian product of open sets belonging to the topological spaces X and Y, respectively. These sets are then defined to be the open sets of the product topology X x Y.